# Unable to get the value from a response that has a hyphen

Tags: javascript, json, karate

I have a response like

```
{
"id-claim" : "kajdfhskljf",
"documentation" : "https//documnets"
}
```

I'm trying to do
`And print response.id-claim`
but it doesn't print anything. I can get the value of documentation though. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is a JavaScript / JSON thing, where `-` is a special character, that will be evaluated as a "minus sign" so you have to do this:

```
And print response['id-claim']
```