# append global header to every request

Tags: karate

We have many karate tests and now we have a new requirement to send `X-Host-Forwarder` header with every request to server.

I added global request headers using

`karate.configure('headers', { 'X-Host-Forwarder': 'account-hub' });`

In each feature file we have feature based headers e.g.

```
configure headers = { Accept: #(mediaType), 'Content-Type': #(mediaType), 'Api-Key': #(apiKey) }
```

How can I **append** `X-Host-Forwarder` global header on every request along with headers specified in each feature file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the quotes around `X-Host-Forwarder`. Your question is not clear at all, but I suspect that is the [issue you faced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59290767/143475).

So it works, you can try this and see for yourself:

```
* karate.configure('headers', { 'X-Host-Forwarder': 'account-hub' })
* url 'https://httpbin.org/get'
* method get
```

To do this globally, do it in `karate-config.js`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karate-configjs

If the question is about appending, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54303725/143475

Comment: i updated my question but I will check out your references.

Comment: @ArunGopalpuri the thing is `configure headers` is designed to be done only once per test. the good news is that if you use `karate.get()` you can get variable values in the JS routine and that should solve your problem with a single global headers routine - refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#configure-headers

Comment: Does it mean I have to update all my tests now? Each feature file has `configure headers` as we use versioning with headers e.g. `application/json; v=1`so it can be different for each test (as version can be different for different apis).

Comment: @ArunGopalpuri maybe yes, but is that really a big issue ? create a good central function and enjoy the feeling of deleting one or two lines of code from each test :) how `karate configure` works is clearly documented in the readme and multiple examples. if you have "clever" tests, you have to write clever code, there is no "short cut"